# Scale pdf to DINA4 and then add a 3mm black margin around it (python)

Tags: python, pdf, scale, margin

I have to check if a pdf file has the format of DIN-A4 and if it's not it should be scaled to DIN-A4 (210mm x 297mm). After this on each side of the pdf should be added a 3mm black margin, so that the document has a width of 216mm and a height of 303mm in the end.

I don't find any solutions for python.

I know how to crop a image, but not how to scale it up and especially not how to add a margin.

Comment: Can easily be done in PyMuPDF, see below. Presumably, a page already in A4 should still get that border? Best is to forcedly take each input page, scale it to A4 (whether or not already in that format), and embed it in a page 3 mm larger on each side.

Comment: @KJ Yeah, you are right 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
src = fitz.open("input.pdf")  # input PDF
doc = fitz.open()  # the new output PDF
a4 = fitz.paper_rect("a4")
# 3 mm are about 8.5 points
border = 8.5
a4plus = a4 + (0, 0, 2*border, 2*border) # output page size
# A4 inside target rectangle
tar_rect = a4plus + (border, border, -border, -border)

#border position
bor_rect = a4plus + (border/2, border/2, -(border/2), -(border/2))

for page in src:
    npage = doc.new_page(width=a4plus.width, height=a4plus.height)
    # draw a white rectangle with a 3 mm border on output page
    npage.draw_rect(bor_rect, color=0, width=border)
    # insert source page re-scaled to A4 into it
    npage.show_pdf_page(tar_rect, src, page.number)
doc.save("output.pdf")
```